# Upload progress with AFNetworking issue

Tags: python, ios, afnetworking

situation: 
i am using AFNetworking to upload some data via a http-post request from my iOS App to my webserver. Specifically its some parameters and an image.

my problem:
It works fine except of the upload progress visualisation. It is way too fast. So my progress-bar is showing an complete upload after some miliseconds and than it waits for lets say 3-4 seconds until it is complete.

It looks like its only measuring the parameter dictionary upload and not the image upload. Could it also depend on what the server sends back? I am running python...

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6f);

NSMutableDictionary* paramsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[table dictRespresentation]];
[paramsDictionary setValue:[NetConnectionManager generateRequestID:table] forKey:@"table"];
[paramsDictionary setValue:someString forKey:@"string"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/table" parameters:paramsDictionary constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"picture" fileName:@"picture.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    self.uploadProgress = (100.0f / totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * totalBytesWritten;
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes   progress: %f", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, self.uploadProgress);

}];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

}
];

[self.httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```